# Slowndown stays after using and removing a lot of objects

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I'm stuck on this one. I'm working on a game. I use this piece of code to create some eyecandy of debree falling. When an object is destroyed i spawn some rubble and let is fly over the screen. But... when i use this a lot, slowdown is there and even when all the objects are gone the slowdown stays. The good old 50fps won't come back anymore :( Is there some kind of memoryleak in here i'm missing? Or is there a better way to do this?

```
public function destroyBlock(xPos,yPos,nrObjects) {

        for (var debree = 0; debree < nrObjects; debree++) {

            debreeObject = new mc_ground();
                debreeObject.x = xPos;
                debreeObject.y = yPos;
                debreeObject.scaleX = Math.random() * 0.3 + 0.1;
                debreeObject.scaleY = debreeObject.scaleX;
                debreeObject.speedX = Math.random()* 5 - 2.5;
                debreeObject.speedY = -Math.random() * 10 - 5;
            stageObject.addChild(debreeObject);

            debreeObject.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveDebree);

        }

    }

    public function moveDebree(e:Event) {

        e.target.x += e.target.speedX;

        e.target.y += e.target.speedY;
        e.target.speedY += gravity;

        if (e.target.y > stageHeight) {

            e.target.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveDebree);
            e.target.parent.removeChild(e.target);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you verified that an equal amount of objects created by the loop actually pass through `if (e.target.y > stageHeight) {..}`?

Comment: Yeh, i tried another way, like fading the alpha of the objects and then use `if (e.target.alpha == 0)` for removing the objects. Same thing.

Comment: verify this IF statement  if (e.target.y > stageHeight) I have a feeling you are not getting a good stageHeight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and I can't see any performance loss. Are you sure this is not due to another part of your game?

[Your code only on wonderfl](http://wonderfl.net/c/ranC)

Comment: Thanks a lot man, this is so weird. I still have the problem and all tests indicate that the problem is this. I tested different options. Maybe it's not the code in general. Can it be that when flash suffers slowdown from to many objects on screen it doesn't get to it's old speed anymore? To me it's no problem, but it is a little weird isn't it?

Comment: And still... when i do extreme things (thousands of objects with this code) and go to debug -> list objects it shows me about 22670 objects. So there must be something left there. I'll test some more then.

Comment: I got this thing fixed. I forgot to change back from the alpha to the y-code. The above code works perfectly but... if i try `if (e.target.alpha == 0)` it doesn't. I changed it to `if (e.target.alpha < 0.1)` and things are all smooth. Thanks everyone for your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend implementing an [Object Pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern) for this type of activity. Because creating `new mc_ground()` objects will slow things down, especially in loops. Memory allocation and deallocation can be slow; and with garbage collection you could end up with a lot of things in memory at any given time.

Once your pool is created, then you can do something like `debreeObject = myDebreePool.getFromPool()` which will give you an object from the pool. Then after you call `removeChild` on that object, return it to the pool with something like `myDebreePool.returnToPool(oldDebreeObject)`.

Depending on your needs, you may need the object pool to reset the state of the object when you return it. Otherwise it might remember old data that is no longer needed. However, given your sample code, I don't think that will be necessary.

If you correctly implement your object pool, you should see a significant performance gain in this type of scenario.